# How to stop elastic scrolling (aka scroll bounce, aka page overscroll effect) on iOS home screen links?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, scroll, iphone-standalone-web-app

I managed to disable the scrolling overshot effect ("rubber band"?) on my web page by overriding the touchmove event. This is working well on mobile safari.

But when I add a shortcut to my page in the iPad home screen, the effect is again active.

How can I disable it there too?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the method you used to stop the rubber-banding effect is:

JQuery

```
$(document).bind(
  'touchmove',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
);
```

or

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener(
  'touchmove',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  false
);
```

If it was neither of those, try that first.

However, if you are still having trouble with elasticity, try using something like [this](https://gist.github.com/amolk/1599412), or this:

Javascript

```
function BlockMove(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
}
```

HTML

```
<body ontouchmove="BlockMove(event);">
</body>
```

Comment: Using the `BlockMove` function on html worked for me